# RxJS Observable - return if first event not emitted in first x mins, otherwise continue for x+y mins

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, server-sent-events

RxJS/Angular experts, need your input/pointers

I am trying to put a logic on the Observable (created from http call)

I want to return (come out of the waiting and discontinue subscription on the observable) if first event is not emitted from Observable in first 3 mins

But if first event is emitted in first 3 mins, I want to continue with subscription & get the data for total of 10 mins (from the time subscription started)

As of now, using takeUntil(timer(1000 * 60 * 10)  to wait for total 10 mins, but want to divide this wait in 3 mins, and if some response -> then only extend by 7mins

**pseudo code**

```js
Observable
.pipe(
    takeUntil(timer(10* 60 * 1000)),
    map (res => {}),
    filter()
)
.subscribe(

)
```

Note: the above call wraps on the EventSource SSE call

I thought to use out of box RxJS timeout, but does not fit to my requirement

Comment: @curious: [tag:sse] is for x86 SIMD.  HTTP Server Sent Events has a different tag.  Please mouseover tags to make sure they're right when using them for the first time, especially if they have short names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[A working stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sbjozf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Use [**`race`**](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/race.html) operator for the first x mins condition, **[`takeUntil`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/takeuntil.html)** is passed into http request for the second condition :

```
 fistTimerBenchMark$ = timer(3000).pipe(switchMap(x => throwError('ended before 3s')));

 //Mock http request
 mockHttp$ = timer(2000,2000).pipe(map(x => 'http respones'),takeUntil(timer(10000)));

 ngOnInit(){
      race(this.fistTimerBenchMark, this.mockHttp$)
      .subscribe( x => console.log(x),  err => console.log(err))
 }
```

Additionaly, I used **`throwError`** to complete the observable for the first x min condition, since unsubscribe it in an observable's pipeline or subscriber is not a good convention.

Answer (score 1):

using a combination of timeout and takeUntil could also solve your problem.
Take a look at the following simple example:

```js
    //emit value every 4s
    const source = interval(4000);
    //after 11 seconds, emit value
    const myTimer = timer(11000);
    //modify timeout time to see what happens if no value comes from the interval
    // i.e. set timeout to 3s
    const example = source.pipe(
      timeout(5000),
      catchError(error => of("Error while request")),
      takeUntil(myTimer));

    //output: 0,1
    const subscribe = example.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

The `timeout` fires if no data come from the `source`. `takeUntil` is the limit of time to read the `source`. If the `timer` fires, the observable is finished.